# Two real square matrices $A$ and $B$ satisfy the conditions $A^{2002}=B^{2003}=I$ and $AB=BA$. Prove that $A+B+I$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I have solved the problem upto this. How I can proceed after this. Please give a hint.

Comment: Did you loose the next lines?

Comment: yeah. After this I got stuck.

Comment: How about trying to show $(p, q) = 1$? Thus there exist polynomials $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ such that $up + vq = 1$. Hence $u(B)p(B)+v(B)q(B) = I$ and we can conclude $x = 0$

Comment: Yeah. It will be a good one. If we can show p,q do not have any common root, job will be done. how to do that.

Comment: Use the fact that if $z$ and $z + 1$ both lie on the unit circle in the complex plane, then $z = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt 3 i}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(A+B+I)x=0$ for some vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then we get $(B+I)x=-Ax$. Then we have $-A^{2}x=A(B+I)x=(B+I)Ax=-(B+I)^2x.$ Continuing in this way, we obtain $(B+I)^kx=(-1)^{k}A^{k}x$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. As $A^{2002}=I$, we get $(B+I)^{2002}x=x$. Then we can write the following $$((B+I)^{2002}-I)x=(B^{2003}-I)x=0 \hspace{0.7cm}\mbox{ Recall that } B^{2003}=I.$$ In other words, taking the polynomials $p(t)=(t+1)^{2002}-1$ and $q(t)=t^{2003}-1$, we have just got $$p(B)x=q(B)x=0.$$ We now prove that $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are two relatively prime polynomials. For this, it is enough to show that $p(t),q(t)$ do not have any common root. To the contrary, assume that $\alpha$ be a common root of $p(t),q(t)$. Then $\alpha^{2003}=1=(\alpha+1)^{2002}$. From this, it follows that both $\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$ lie on the unit circle. Hence $|\alpha|=|\alpha+1|$. This implies that $\alpha=\frac{-1\pm i\small{\sqrt{3}}}{2}$ which is a contradiction because we can see that this value of $\alpha$ does not satisfy $\alpha^{2003}=1$ and $(\alpha+1)^{2002}=1$. Since $\alpha$ is any arbitrary, so there exist no common root of $p(t)$ and $q(t)$, which implies that $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are relatively prime polynomials. Thus there exists non-zero polynomials $r(t),s(t)$ such that $r(t)p(t)+s(t)q(t)=1$. From this we get that $$r(B)p(B)+s(B)q(B)=I\implies x=r(B)p(B)x+s(B)q(B)x\implies x=0$$ as $p(B)x=q(B)x=0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence $A+B+I$ must be invertible.